# Insert account to file

Tags: javascript, file, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe

I'm using insert file to insert account is created and the content will like this:
`{ "LoginSuccessfully" :  { "emailAddress": "HhGuim@mailinator.com", "password": "abcd123" } }`

But we have a lot of type of account so i will use append file to insert more record to the file, and it will look like this:
`{ "ABC" :  { "emailAddress": "HhGuim@mailinator.com", "password": "abcd123" }, "EDF":  { "emailAddress": "HhGuim@mailinator.com", "password": "abcd123" } }`

ABC or EDF is type of that account, so can when we call append file, we can overwrite the account of that type we want, like i want append account with type ABC, and it only overwrite old account ABC and the EDF will not change

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you use the JSON format. It means you need to read file content first, then parse it to an object, change any properties you want, and write it again to the file. For example:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const promisifiedReadFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const promisifiedWriteFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

(async function() {
  const data = await promisifiedReadFile('data.json');
  const dataObj = JSON.parse(data.toString());

  dataObj['ABC'] = { "emailAddress": "HhGuim@mailinator.com", "password": "abcd456" };

  await promisifiedWriteFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(dataObj));
})();
```